# Buying Cervelo P2 vs P-Series

Tags: road-bike, disc-brake, triathlon

I'm looking to buy my first tri bike and am considering between a Cervelo 2016 P2 (rim-brake) and the new 2021 P-Series (disc-brake).

The P2 is brand new, but it's an old stock my LBS has on hand, and would cost me about $1k less than the new P-Series. Should I get the P2, given that it's much cheaper? Or is there any downside to buying an older version of the bike? Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Do read the FAQ to learn how the site works. In particular, we consider questions about shopping for specific bicycles to be off topic; specific products will become outdated. It is possible to make some general statements in this case, but the question may be closed - don't take it personally. You could rephrase it to ask what are the potential downsides to buying a rim brake bike, however.

Comment: You might also ask if there's any downside to buying a carbon-frame bike that's been sitting in the shop for 4 years, though I suspect the answer is "no."

Answer (score 2):

Cervélo advertises the P-Series to have less drag and weight than the P3 (and therefore P2). Which components/groupset are installed on the two bikes? What’s the overall cost? 1k$ is not *that* much of a difference when the bike costs several thousand.

Are you riding in bad weather (and/or hilly terrain) and can make good use of the disc brakes? One thing I also like about disc brakes is that you avoid wear on those very expensive aero wheels.

If the P-Series comes with electronic shifting I’d definitely pick it over the P2.

Answer (score 2):

Disc vs. rim brakes have some trade-offs. The whole industry is moving to disc brakes, as you know. I think it can be said that disc brakes objectively perform better, but the gains for most riders in most situations are small. However, here are some considerations.

- Many triathletes (and cyclists) acquire aerodynamic race wheels. If you are on rim brakes, most race wheels have carbon braking surfaces, which are fussier. Braking is poorer, you need special brake pads, and you will need to switch out the brake pads when going to race wheels (or else you have embedded aluminum fragments in your regular pads, which will then destroy your carbon wheels). While most racers won't have prolonged downhills, if you do, you shouldn't drag your brakes on carbon wheels. Also, most riders should avoid using latex tubes in carbon rim brake wheels, because latex will fail at lower temperatures than butyl. That said, it's possible to get wheels with aluminum rims and aerodynamic carbon fairings. The [FLO 60 Aluminum + Carbon](https://flocycling.com/products/flo-60-aluminum-carbon), [Bontrager Aeolus Comp](https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/equipment/cycling-components/bike-wheels/road-bike-wheels/bontrager-aeolus-comp-5-tlr-road-wheel/p/21803/), and [Hed's Jet Plus](https://store.hedcycling.com/jet-plus-rim-brake/) series of wheels are three examples I recall.
- Continuing the above, if you are on disc wheels, it's no problem to just swap in a set of carbon wheels. Because the rims don't wear, you could even use those as your daily set of wheels.
- The industry is moving to disc brakes, and rim brake rims should cease to get new technological developments. That said, many people may be selling off their old rim brake wheels at a discount.
- Disc rims let manufacturers design aerodynamic wheels for wider tires than rim brake systems. For example, Hed recommends a 23mm front tire to optimize aerodynamics on their Jet wheels. Zipp and Enve designed their latest wheels to optimize aerodynamics with a 28mm tire. Wider tires are more comfortable than narrow ones. This would be worth considering in a long-distance triathlon, especially since you have to run a half or full marathon after the bike leg. You can certainly disregard this and run a wider tire on a rim brake bike, although you'd want to note the frame's maximum clearance.

Focusing on the bike, there may be some tradeoffs here as well. Unfortunately, I'm not as familiar with the triathlon bicycle segment. However, I think that some of the more recent developments for tri bikes include integrating options for nutrition and hydration into the bike. From a glance, the 2016 P2 appears to have only one set of downtube bottle mounts and a top tube mount for a bento box (colloquial name for a small pack for snacks, derived from the [Japanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bento) take-out meal, although similar meal formats occur elsewhere in East Asia), although you can add a behind the saddle bottle cage mount aftermarket. The current P-series appears to have the behind the saddle mount already integrated with the seatpost, and it comes stock with an aero bottle and an aero integrated bento box. These advantages may not be large, however.

One that may be worth asking about or researching is the cable routing. Internal cables are nice, but if they are poorly routed through the frame, there will be more drag when you shift. Also, it can be harder to service some models. I have no idea if Cervelo made any improvements, or if the cabling on the 2016 bikes was problematic at all. This is merely a suggestion to look at. Internal routing has probably improved on average from 2016 to now.

Last, the P-series 105 model appears to have cable disc brakes. In my (admittedly limited) experience and from interactions with other riders, many cable discs have much weaker braking than hydraulic disc brakes. With cables, you do have to replace the cables and housing regularly, whereas hydraulic brakes and hoses often do not need to be touched after setup. One exception to hydraulic systems' generally lower maintenance needs: if you travel, then especially if you need to disconnect the brakes to pack the bike, you may need to bleed hydraulic brakes at the destination.

Last, cycling in general is an expensive sport, and it's not just the bike. You might want a good race suit for comfort as well as aerodynamics - I would highly recommend thinking about this. You might want a good aerodynamic helmet. You definitely will want a comfortable pair of shoes, and riders may need to experiment with both shoes and insoles. You may want to change the saddle, and again, many riders need to experiment with these. You might want a power meter to help you pace yourself and to help improve training (albeit you have to put some cognitive work into training with power to maximize the benefit). You could put the savings in buying the older bike into these areas, or other triathlon equipment.